# Create cookies when user clicks a button

Tags: python, django, cookies

I want that when a person clicks a button on my page, a function in the view is called which creates cookies on user's machine and then store the cookie id in my models.

Template(HTML page):

```
<form action="#" method="get">
        <p style="text-align: center;"> 
            <input type="submit" class="optOutButton" value="Opt-Out" name="optOutButton"> </p>
    </form>
```

Views.py

```
class UserOptOut(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'debug/opt-out-child.html'    

    def user_opt_out(request):
        if(request.GET.get('optOutButton')):
            response = HttpResponse('Hahahaha')
            response.set_cookie('id', 1)
            return response
        if request.COOKIES.has_key( 'id' ):
            value = request.COOKIES[ 'id' ]
        return render_to_response(debug/opt-out-child.html)
```

But, when I click the button nothing happens. Can somebody help me with what I am doing wrong?

Comment: possibly GET # is considered a null op by the browser, that does nothing. Try using action="?R={{random}}". Otherwise it seems to me it should work.

Answer (score 0):

`user_opt_out` is not a method that will be called automatically in a TemplateView. You should probably put this in the `get` method instead.

Although since you explicitly render and return a full response from your method anyway, I don't know why you've used a class-based view at all: just use a normal view function.